# Split array into separate arrays

Tags: php

I have an array `$products` which contains a non-fixed number of elements.

I need to split this array into 3 individual arrays. The first two arrays should contain an equal number of elements and the last array may contain less.

So for example if `$products` contains 16 elements, the output should be:

- Array 1 contains: 6 elements
- Array 2 contains: 6 elements
- Array 3 contains: 4 elements

In the event that there are less than 3 elements in `$products`, then the relevant arrays need to just return empty.

How can I do this? I tried using `array_chunk()` but doesn't quite do what I want.

`$distributed = array_chunk($products, 3, true);`

Comment: In your example why 6,6,4? What is there that eliminates 7,7,2 or 8,8,0? Can you elaborate on what the goal is/what it is you require?

Comment: A few sample inputs and the exact desired output would make this question more clear and helpful.  The title is a little too vague to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer:

`$distributed = array_chunk($products, (int)ceil(count($products)/3), true);`